# No content in 401 response after upgrade springBoot to 2.6.2

Tags: spring-boot, security, error-handling

The default error handling does not return the proper information;
I upgraded the SpringBoot version from 2.5.2 to 2.6.2
Case scenario:
Sending get method without authentication:

Response from postman for springBoot 2.6.2:
[springBoot version 2.6.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBSOQ.png)

Response from postman for springBoot 2.5.2:
[springBoot version 2.5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMixN.png)

Is the lack of return content an intended action?
I going to use @ControllerAdvice to resolve this isue.

project details:

```
 <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What do you see as the response code after `Spring Boot 2.6.2` update? `401` or `500`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the new filter `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` that comes with `Spring 2.6.2`. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29383) you can find someone who has tried various situations with the same issue.

In another `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` related issue, it was said:

> The ErrorPageSecurityFilter use HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI() as uri parameter for the WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(uri, authentication) method, which contains the context path. The JavaDoc notes that the context-path should be excluded in the uri parameter.

I think it is because the `context-path` is not excluded in the uri parameter as in the description [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28953#issuecomment-1004634869).

Maybe it will be helpful for you to take a look at the suggestion [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29299#issuecomment-1013035440).